# unable to start listening for the server following cowboy guide

Tags: erlang, cowboy

I'm trying to follow the [cowboy guide here](https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.5/guide/getting_started/) and I cannot seems to understand how to *start* the http server. The program compiles and start, but there's no http server that listen on port 8080.

Running `make run` do seems to compiles OK and running the `i()` command I do see `hello_erlang_sup` process like the guide page says.

But after applying the changes to the `hello_world_app:start/2` and run `make run` or `make` no http listener is available.

I've also added `erlang:display(inside_start),` inside the function and was hopeful that it might print to the terminal, nope, maybe this function is not called? But how can I investigate that as a new comer to the language and cowboy, there's like 100 files already for a hello world ;).

Here's the function as reference:

```
start(_Type, _Args) ->
    erlang:display(inside_start),
    Dispatch = cowboy_router:compile([
        {'_', [
            {"/", hello_handler, []}
        ]}
    ]),
    {ok, _} = cowboy:start_clear(my_http_listener, [{port, 8080}], #{
        env => #{dispatch => Dispatch}
    }),
    hello_world_sup:start_link().
```

In case that help / have impact:

```
$ erl --version
Erlang/OTP 21 [erts-10.1.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]

$ uname -a
Linux 4.18.16-arch1-1-ARCH x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Some naive questions that I cannot seems to find answers atm:

1) Do I have to do something to actually "start" anything, or the `make run` is enough? i.e. I tried to run the binary that is in `_rel/hello_erlang/bin/hello_erlang_release` with start | stop | console.

2) Maybe cowboy is not the right option for me to start. I'm currently interested in seeing if Erlang is a good fit for me. Maybe I should not start with web or should not use any library to eliminate the confusion and focus on Erlang alone. Any suggestions?

I'm most certainly missing something highly obvious but can't find it.

Appreciate any help,
Thanks

Comment: If you are really starting with Erlang, it is, in my opinion, too ambitious to start with an application like cowboy. You should first be sure that you master the syntax and data structures, and that you understand the OTP which is the key of most Erlang application. It is really worth and does not need so much time. If you did not already found it, I recommend you the ["learn you some erlang"](https://learnyousomeerlang.com/content) web site.

Comment: To answer question two, you should start with what @Pascal suggested and [this blog](http://howistart.org/posts/erlang/1/) posted by the same author. IMO I find erlang HTTP frameworks to be very verbose compared to working with vanilla processes and TCP servers.

Comment: thanks @Pascal and Pie I'll do that for sure than. I'm used to the simplicity of Go's net/http package with no library / framework. I understand that I might need to start from the bottom-up to understand what's going on in Erlang.